# Cart Price Rules - shipping discount apply twice

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7.2

I'm trying to put Cart Price Rule on orders over 149 and less than 168 but it's sometimes applied twice

The shipping price is 15
Fixed discount 8 ( sometimes applies 16 )

[image]

[image]